# Django - update field whose name given dynamically

Tags: django

I am creating an API in Django to update a table.
I have a table in following format with time field as string.

```
time    P_1       P_2         P_3
----    ---       ---         ---
22:00    1        0            0
05:34    0        1            1
```

The input field will be

```
"entry_time" = {"P_1":["22:10","04:34"],
                "P_2":["04:34"]
               }
```

How can I achieve this?

I tried many places but I dint find solution to pick the field name of model in runtime and update that field or create new entry if it is not there.

Please help.

Edit 1: My models.py is as below

```
from mongoengine import fields, Document

class ProductEntry(Document):

    id = fields.IntField(primary_key=True)
    time = fields.StringField(required=True)
    P_1 = fields.StringField(default=0)
    P_2 = fields.StringField(default=0)
    P_3 = fields.StringField(default=0)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how this is supposed to work, could you provide the code for your model?

Comment: @BrianH.I have updated the question